# AWS Service Proxy to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are exposing a AWS Api Gateway which needs to act as proxy and push body as message to AWS SQS. Our API gateway body can be array of object which we need to parse and send each object to SQS as separate message. Is there any way to achieve this without using Lambda ?

Comment: Can you write a Docker-containerized app that handles this using Amazon ECS to push messages into SQS? Curious why you would prefer not to use Lambda--is it cost concerns?

Comment: I am exploring my options. If i write lambda, job of this lambda is just loop through api body array and create sqs message for each array item. So wondering if we can achieve this within API gateway iteself and create multiple SQS message out of single request

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, for something as simple as parsing a message and posting to SQS, I don't believe you need Lambda, no. Lambdas are designed for serverless-architecture. That is, when you don't have a server and you still want to run code. In this case, you do have a server behind your API Gateway, so you don't need Lambda (unless you want fancy branching error handling). You can use your API Gateway directly, yep. Here's a code review I found:

https://dzone.com/articles/creating-aws-service-proxy-for-amazon-sqs